# Selenium hangs when switch to frame

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've recently updated Selenium Webdriver to 2.44 to be able to use it on Firefox ESR 32.

The problem is that it now just hangs when trying to switch to a frame which haven't been loaded. The website I am trying to test uses several different iframes and I rely heavily on switching frames in my test scripts. If I add a sleep before the switch the test runs without any problem, but I really do not want to add a sleep to every switch since my test would be sooo much slower.

I'm using Python to run the scripts, but I don't feel that it would matter since it all boils down to a Selenium Webdriver call.

Anyone else that has encountered this issue or have any suggestions on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using static `sleep`, it will wait irrespective of the page/iframe loading and hence you are seeing slowness in execution.

Make use of Webdriver's advance dynamic waiting strategies as mentioned [here.](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)
In your case you need to implement correct [Explicit Waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) and it will wait only for required amount of time.

Comment: no, the problem is not that it is slow. The problem is that it hangs. I can wait for hours and it will still not proceed. Also, this is a problem that only occurred with the esr 32 version of firefox and not with esr 24 version of firefox. So our test scripts has not changed in any way that could explain this problem.